# How to remove null from a map?

Tags: apex

```
  for(sObject con : ListOfCon){
            for(String mapfields : MapMappingTable.keySet()){
              allfields += mapfields+'='+con.get(MapMappingTable.get(mapfields));
              allfields += '&';
              //allfields = allfields.replaceAll('\"[^\"]*\":null','');
              System.debug('@@@@ allfields::::::'+allfields);
            }
  }
```

I am getting debug as:

```
allfields::::::nullCustomField1 = some texthere&CustomField2=data1& Customfield3 = data3 &
```

My problem is I am getting null added in first field and I am trying to remove that, and similarly I am trying to remove '&' from last position

Comment: Have you initialised `allfields`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `&` char and prevent the null, you can do this:

```
  String ampersand = '';
  String allfields = '';
  for(sObject con : ListOfCon){
        for(String mapfields : MapMappingTable.keySet()){
          allfields += ampersand + mapfields+'='+con.get(MapMappingTable.get(mapfields));
          ampersand = '&';
        }
  }
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

For performance, I recommend using String.join rather than the other provided answers:

```
String[] values = new String[0];
for(SObject con: listofcon) {
    for(String key: MapMappingTable.keySet()) {
        values.add(key+'='+con.get(MapMappingTable.get(key)));
    }
    allFields = String.join(values, '&');
}
System.debug(allFields);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use String methods as follows:

```
String str = 'nullCustomField1 = some texthere&CustomField2=data1& Customfield3 = data3 &';

str.removeStart('null').removeEnd('&');
```

Refer [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Initialise `allfields` to avoid null appending first. Use [`removeEnd()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method to remove last occurring `&`.

```
String allfields = '';
for(sObject con : ListOfCon){
    for(String mapfields : MapMappingTable.keySet()){
        allfields += mapfields+'='+con.get(MapMappingTable.get(mapfields));
        allfields += '&';
    }
    allfields.removeEnd('&');
    System.debug('@@@@ allfields:::::: '+allfields);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List.get()` returns the list element stored at the specified index. 
I believe you list `Con` does not have a element at index `con.get(MapMappingTable.get(mapfields)`.

You can check for null before adding the element something like

```
if(con.get(MapMappingTable.get(mapfields)) != null{

             //code your logic here

}
```

let me know if this helps?

Comment: Hey I got rid of null from starting by initializing allfields but how do I remove '&' from last position

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but should work.
Initialize allfields

```
String allFields = '';
```

and then..

```
allfields += (allFields == null || String.isBlank(allFields)) ? '' : '&' + mapfields + '=' + con.get(MapMappingTable.get(mapfields));
```